# Don't understand why this JavaScript function can be called one way but not the other

Tags: javascript

I recently started learning JavaScript for the purpose of creating HTML5 games, and I've come across a behavior that I'm having a hard time understanding.

As an example, I have a constructor that initializes new sprites with an array of actions that they should carry out every time the game updates (such as animating, moving, etc.). [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9WN5/) demonstrates a basic implementation.

Essentially, I'm confused as to why this doesn't work...

```
Sprite = function () {

    this.actions = [this.animate];
};

Sprite.prototype = {

    animate: function () { /* animate the sprite */ },

    update: function () {

        this.actions[0]();  // doesn't do anything (?)
    }
};
```

...but this does

```
Sprite = function () {

    this.actions = [this.animate];
    this.holder = 'whatever';
};

Sprite.prototype = {

    animate: function () { /* animate the sprite */ },

    update: function () {

        this.holder = this.actions[0];
        this.holder();  // executes animate function as desired
    }
};
```

To my inexperienced eyes, both examples seem like they should do the exact same thing. So why does nothing happen if I call `this.actions[0]()` directly, but if I assign `this.actions[0]` to `this.holder` and then call `this.holder()`, it works just fine?

Comment: change to this.actions[0]. Remove ( ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a function is called, a value will be assigned to a local variable called `this` inside the function.

Unless you have done something to change it (e.g. `new`, `bind()`, `call()`, `apply()`), the value will be the object on which it is called. With `foo.bar()` `this === foo` inside the `bar` function.

`this.actions[0]()` makes `this` equal to the value of the `actions` property

`this.holder()` makes `this` equal to whatever the value of `this` is in the calling function.

Your function must depend on the value of `this` to do whatever it does.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how `this.holder() makes "this" equal to whatever the value of "this" is in the calling function`? I'm not able to comprehend why should it be any different specially when `this.holder = this.actions[0]`.

Comment: `foo.bar.baz()` - inside `baz`, `this` is the same as the value of `bar` since that is object on which `baz()` was called. `this.holder()` calls `holder` on `this`. `this.actions[0]()` calls `0()` on `actions`.

Comment: I was still slightly unclear on things until I read your response to Ravi's question, but now I think I finally understand. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to fix this:

```
Sprite = function () {
    this.actions = [this.animate.bind(this)];
};
```

Or:

```
update: function () {
    this.actions[0].call(this);
}
```

Comment: I accepted Quentin's answer because I was looking for an explanation more than a solution, but I think the options you provided for accomplishing the task at hand are very helpful (I'll most likely be using the second one for my purposes).

Comment: @user2703034: Yep, I realize this didn't answer your original question, but figured it would be useful.